# When are kill skills triggered?

Tags: borderlands-2

There are a lot of skills in the skill trees of the characters, that are stated as a "Kill Skill", like "[I'm the Juggernaut](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/I%27m_the_Juggernaut)" from [Salvador](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Salvador). There is also stated that they are triggered by a kill ("Killing an enemy gives +4% Damage Reduction for a short time." on the "[I'm the Juggernaut](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/I%27m_the_Juggernaut)" skill).

I'm now interested in when are they triggered on a coop-play. Does the kill from my mate also count to this skill or is it related just to my kills?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kill skills are only activated off of kills you get yourself. Even if a human or AI ally nets a kill, you aren't granted any temporary bonuses.

Answer (score 3):

Kill skills are activated the moment you finish of enemy yourself

No ally can grant you kill skill tied bonus

Only exception from this is of course commando's turret skill

Answer (score 2):

Kill Skill = You finish someone off with **your own attack**, you get a buff.

Answer (score 1):

Your kills will activate your kill skills. You're ally's kills will activate their kill skills. The same goes for AI companions unless you use the Commando's skill or the Mechromancer's Deathtrap skill.